# Is Apple's push notification service reliable?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have an iOS app using push notification but once in a while I'm not getting a notification on my device when I expect to receive one. I would receive all the subsequent notifications. I confirmed with my backend to make sure that all the notifications were sent successfully.

So my question is: is APNs *nearly* 100% reliable or should I just expect to miss some notifications here and there because of intermittent 3G/wifi connection?

I would think that APNs works as a queueing system and retry if it wasn't successful within the first few times.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The APN service will queue messages up -- but Apple doesn't guarantee delivery of all messages. Only the *last* message from an application will be kept in the queue when the user is offline. Additionally, old messages may be deleted.

[Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

> Apple Push Notification Service
>   includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a
>   store-and-forward function. If APNs
>   attempts to deliver a notification but
>   the device is offline, the QoS stores
>   the notification. It retains only one
>   notification per application on a
>   device: the last notification received
>   from a provider for that application.
>   When the offline device later
>   reconnects, the QoS forwards the
>   stored notification to the device. The
>   QoS retains a notification for a
>   limited period before deleting it.

Comment: Thanks for the timely response, Steve. In my case I don't think I have the issue with old or too many messages at one time. It's probably more like one every 10-20 min. and that's being generous.

Comment: Andrew; then, in your case, if the user is offline (no WiFi or 3G) for 20-40 minutes, they may not get 1 or 2 of the messages.

Comment: xydev, I was going to check with our a few of our users to see if this is consistent with their experience. However I don't think it would be fair to modify the content of my question if this wasn't the case. So, yes, I'm marking it answered.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Good to know this in advance before users wonder where their notification went!

Answer (score 1):

I have an azure website (and mobile service, service bus, db, active directory etc) that sends push notifications to a xamarin app on a windows phone and an iphone.  The first notification is received by both.  The second notification is only received by the windows phone, it doesnt make it to the iphone.  If I send another notification, it is received by both.  So I investigated the behaviour at bit more and found that if I machine gun a series of notifications (hand typed one per 2 seconds) the windows phone received them all but the iphone only receives the first one.  But if I wait a while and send a notification it is received by both devices.  The next test is to see if the notifications are always received with a 5 minute gap.  Sent two messages with a five minutes gap in between, both windows phone and iphone received both notifications.