# Apple Push Notification Race Conditions

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Say I send 5 notifications, targeted at the same user, from my server at APNS from a loop.

I assume these messages will get load balanced over multiple APNS servers, and all arrive totally out of sequence on the user's device, no?

Unless Apple reorders them on the device by send time?

Comment: You can't be certain. Almost a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898382/2124535

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) reliability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897575/apns-apple-push-notification-service-reliability)

Comment: @nathan i'm talking in the case that every message does get delivered, what about the order

Comment: If reliability isn't guaranteed it also implies order.