# Show view instead default notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an app for Android using Firebase which acts like a multi-factor authentication, user logins and receives a dialog asking for confirmation on smartphone.

I'm developing similar app on iPhone, also using Firebase.
I was able to receive the notification (sent from Firebase Console) in an iPhone, however I have some doubts regarding this.

In my android App, I implemented it so that no default notification appears when a notification is received, instead it shows a View with a Yes / No button.

In iOS, all tutorials I have seen the user needs to first 'click' the notification on top bar, so that you can interact and then open a View...

So my questions (I'm new to iOS development) are basically:

- Is it possible not to display the notification (on top bar) and open a view directly?
- When the user is signing up, he needs to read a QRCode, then send notification to server, and then server sends back a notification answer with Sucess/Failure, in the case the server answered, can I choose to show 'nothing' (no default notification)? I don't mean silent notifications, because they are not taken as priority.
- The server answer with a custom json, but I read somewhere notifications in iOS should have an specif format?

These are basically my questions, I know they are kinda basic, but most tutorials I found are from older iOS versions, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about notifications from the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS).
To answer your questions in order:

> 1. Is it possible not to display the notification (on top bar) and open a view directly?

You cannot change the default style for system wide push notifications. The user can even disable notifications for your application at any point. However, you can send an [Actionable Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types) and implement a Yes/No decision this way without the need of opening the app itself. This might be most similar to your desired outcome.

> 2. Can I send a notification without showing a view?

[Silent Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently) are most likely the best option for you, if you do not want to continuously ask your server after the login request. For more information on reliability of APNS read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897575/apns-apple-push-notification-service-reliability).

What you should also think of: If your app is opened while receiving a notification, no system wide notification view is shown, regardless of whether this notification was silent or not.

> 3. Is there a specific format for notifications?

The notification needs to be delivered in a format that is [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification).
If you can't send all your relevant json within the push notification itself, you can instead just send a url or flag indicating that your app can download new content from the server. This can be perfectly done in the notification handler.

Comment: Since I read in one of your links that if the App is in foreground, then no message/dialog will be displayed to the user, that means, in the case server confirms registration (with a push to iPhone), I won't need to worry and I won't use silent notification because in my case the app will be in foreground (waiting for confirmation), is that correct?