# UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications only returns empty array

Tags: swift, swift3, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I am trying to retrieve all delivered notifications still showing in the notification center but `UNUserNotificationCenter getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:)` just doesn't work. I can get all the pending notifications with `UNUserNotificationCenter getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler:)` but `getDeliveredNotifications` will simply always return a 0 count even though there are notifications on the notification center.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [NUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications only ever returns an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145890/nusernotificationcenter-current-getdeliverednotifications-only-ever-returns-an?rq=1)

Setting the badge number to 0 will clear your remote notifications.

Could that be the problem?