# Android :Trigger after inserting data in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, triggers, parse-cloud-code

I'm using [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com) to store my data through my app. Here is the scenario of what I need:
1- A user will submit a form and the data will be sent and saved in a table in Parse.com
2- After inserting the data into the table, there must be trigger that listen for any insertion and send those data to the app users

My question:

How can I create this trigger?
Should I use Cloud Code?

Appreciate any Help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Cloud Code and a Parse.Cloud.afterSave trigger.

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions

You could then either send a Push Notification to all users or flag the data as new and let your clients query for new data regularly.

Note. If you are planning on iOS app development also I don't believe the apple notification service is a reliable way of pushing new data to users. More on that: [Is Apple's push notification service reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591550/is-apples-push-notification-service-reliable)