# Azure Notification Hub: How to view per message telemetry?

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

On the pricing page for Azure Notification Hubs:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/

It states that "Standard namespaces have access to Per Message Telemetry and Push Notification Services Feedback". I am using a Standard namespace.

The app is sending template based notifications to an iOS app from my back end using the C# Notification Hub client. For example:

```
NotificationOutcome result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(params, tags);
```

The result.State is coming back as Enqueued, but some notifications are not being delivered and I am trying to figure out why. (There are no bad registrations in the hub - I have already checked that.)

In the Azure portal, I can see aggregate metrics of messages received by the hub, errors, etc. - but I cannot seem to view the specific results of a push message to determine why it failed to reach the device, or even if it was successfully handed off to APNS.

How can I see the results of an attempted push? Is this even possible with Azure Notification Hubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try Fiddler+https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608135.aspx ?

Also, as far as i know, Apple does not guarantee the delivery of all notifications. 
1) [Is Apple's push notification service reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591550/is-apples-push-notification-service-reliable)

More of that,
2) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-faq/

"A PNS does not guarantee any SLA for delivering notifications; however, typically a vast majority of push notifications are delivered to target devices within a few minutes (usually within the limits of 10 minutes) from the time they are sent to our platform. "

Comment: Thanks, that Rest API is what I was looking for. Also note: the same functionality is available via the NotificationHubClient GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync method. I am still having an issue, however, in that the NotificationOutcome does not contain the NotificationId, so I have no way to look up the telemetry! See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557991/azure-notification-hub-why-is-notificationoutcome-notificationid-property-empty