# Azure Notification Hub: Why is NotificationOutcome NotificationId Property Empty?

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

Using a Standard Notification Hub, I want to view telemetry for a specific message using the returned NotificationId and either this rest API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608135.aspx

or the NotificationHubClient GetNotificationOutcomeDetailsAsync method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.getnotificationoutcomedetailsasync.aspx

Either way, I need the Notification Message Id that is supposed to be returned from the hub when sending the message.

I am sending the message from the app backend using the SendTemplateNotificationAsync method:

```
NotificationOutcome result = await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(params, tags);
```

After sending the template notification, the result.NotificationId property is empty. How can I get the NotificationId so I can then get the telemetry?

**Update:**

I tried setting the enableTestSend property to true when creating the NotificationHubClient. The result still does not contain a NotificationId.

Currently there is only one device (installation) registered in the hub. Could this be due to a low number of devices receiving the push?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posting this for the benefit of others who may encounter this issue.

I was contacted by an Azure support engineer who helped me resolve the problem. I had recently switched from the Free to the Standard tier, and there is a bug in Notification Hubs related to changing subscription tiers. This required the support engineer to "force sync the cache" - which resolved the issue.

The bug has been fixed and will be rolling out soon. If you encounter this issue I would suggest contacting Azure support.

Comment: We had same problem, after changing plan and some delay it works.

Comment: Also note, you do need to have a [standard subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq) to view per message telemetry data, which I think this falls into