# Does notificationhubs have notifications log?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm wondering if Notificationhubs has a log for all the push notifications it has sent because I couldn't find anything resemble to that on Azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no such out-of-the-box one window where you may access these logs. But there is the per message telemetry that was introduced for Notification Hubs some time ago. Here is the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608135.aspx) about that and basically you need to ask REST API for that.

So you may try to use Fiddler+https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt608135.aspx or implement such functionality in your solution.

Comment: How do you get notification message id though?

Comment: It should be available once you sent the notification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557991/azure-notification-hub-why-is-notificationoutcome-notificationid-property-empty may be helpful.

Comment: Note that in order to get per-message telemetry, your Notification Hub Namespace must be in the Standard pricing tier.